# Trimming ArrayList Elements

Tags: windows, powershell, printing

So, I am writing a PS script to get the permissions from a networked printer. That part is easy enough to get. The output is a little trickier to format and get rid of the fluff, but I've been able to do that as well.

What I need to do, which seems to be escaping me for some reason, is trim the elements of the ArrayList storing the permissions output from the printer.

ArrayList Example:

1. **Element 1:**

   ```
   A;;SWRC;;;S-1-5-21-1951847071-1425869424-1185269715-347033
   ```
2. **Element 5:**

   ```
   A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-1951847071-1425869424-1185269715-111469
   ```

The difference between the two is E1 allows the associated user to send print jobs to the printer. E2 is (essentially) full control of the printer and documents.

How do I slice up those elements to extract the respective permissions of "SWRC" or "OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO"?

Using `$AL[1].TrimStart("A;;")` will get rid of, what I think is, the authentication aspect. But that varying number of permissions for the different users has left my confused. Especially when the full control users don't start with "A;;", they start "A;."

Comment: What's the result supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the 2nd and 3rd `;`-separated field from your input strings, which you can obtain by getting the fields as an array via the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), extracting the fields of interest, and re-joining them with the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join).

The [`.ForEach()` array (collection) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) allows you to efficiently apply the operation on each element of your array list (a [`foreach` *statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) would be slightly faster, but more verbose; the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* would work too, but is slower).

```
# Sample input.
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $arrayList = 
  'A;;SWRC;;;S-1-5-21-1951847071-1425869424-1185269715-347033',
  'A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-1951847071-1425869424-1185269715-111469'

# Adjust the range of indices to extract (1..2) and
# the -join character (';') as needed.
$trimmedList = $arrayList.ForEach({ ($_ -split ';')[1..2] -join ';' })
```

Afterwards, `$trimmedList` contains a collection<sup>[1]</sup> with verbatim elements `;SWRC` and `OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO`.

Note:

- `1..2` is an application of `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), and creates an *array* of integers starting with `1` and ending with `2`, i.e., it is the equivalent of array literal `1, 2`.

  - Adjust as needed; e.g., `1..5` is the equivalent of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.
- Inside an index expression (`[...]`) applied to another array, these integers serve as the indices of the elements to extract, as a sub-array.
  E.g., `[1..2]` returns the 2nd and the 3rd element (given that array indices are `0`-based).

---

<sup>[1] The `.ForEach()` method returns a collection of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, but in most contexts this will behave like an array list (or a regular PowerShell array).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, mklemento0. That does work. I modified it a little, though. So, instead of
```$AL.ForEach({ ($_ -split ';')[1..2] -join ';' })``` I used 
```$AL.ForEach({ ($_ -split ';')[1..5] -join '' })```

So, what does the ```[1..5]``` part do? 

If I changed it to a 5 from a 2 (in your example) I get the perms and the SID together. Not sure of how that plays a role in this.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Dalebert; re `[1..5]`: please see my update; I assumed that you wanted join the extracted fields with `;` again, but you can choose any separator you want.

Comment: Ohhh, yes. That makes sense. Thanks for the tutelage!